# Single line comparison to several values in C

Tags: c, syntax, compare

For example maybe we have an if statement that wants to check if a variable is equal to 4 different values, perhaps something like

```
    if(x == 1,2,3,4){ do something }
```

what is the proper syntax to do this in C? I know the comma works in some other language, I can not seem to figure how not to have several different if checks. The only other thing I could come up with is having to do

```
    if((x == 1)||(x ==2)
```

but I will no doubt have more than 4 and that will get annoying fast. I didn't see any other question like this, if you know of it, point me towards it.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how C works. You have to check each combination separately.

Comment: The thing is that C is close to the hardware. Your CPU cannot compare one value against several at the same time, it is impossible. In higher level languages that have something like "if x is in the interval [1 to n]", you still end up with machine code looking just like `if(x == item[0] || == item[1] ...`. Higher level languages hide away that inefficiency from the programmer, while C does not attempt to sugar-coat it.

Comment: Ah yes, I keep forgetting this about C and the reason I am trying to learn it. Thank you both @Lundin

Answer (score 5):

I would do it with a switch if the values are constant:

```
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        //do something
        break;
}
```

if the numbers are continuous you can use `if (x >= 1 && x <= 4)`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *shorthands*, [as mentioned by mch in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40651599/2173917),

```
 if ( (x >= 1 && x <= 4) || (x >= 10 && x <= 40) || ....) //whatever condition
```

Otherwise, (*not a single line comparison*) in case you are OK with using gcc extensions, there's a feature called [case-range](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges).

There, you can specify a *range* of values. Something like

```
 case 1 ... 5:
```

will be valid.

Finally, a fall-through `switch` case also may come handy, like

```
switch(val)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
           break;

    case 6:
    case 7:

           break;

    default:

            break;
}
```